# Tela Cadastro - Repetição de usuarios

Tags: java, android, api

Tenho um código de post, que realiza o cadastro dos meus usuários, mas eles podem se repetir, gostaria de ajuda pra realizar um código para que os usuários não possam se repetir, porém sou novato em Android e não sei como fazer isso, meu código:

```
public class onbuttonclickHttpPost  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }


            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {


                try {


                    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_users");

                    JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();


                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Api-Key", "XXXXXXXX");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Session-Token", "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjE0LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxNCwiZW1haWwiOiJ0aGlhZ28uY2FtYXJnb0Bldm9sdXRpb25pdC5jb20uYnIiLCJmb3JldmVyIjpmYWxzZSwiaXNzXXXXXXXXmp0aSXXXXXXXXX.hiid9z55BD_THe-oJc6WpTropgVDE7gtw2m9TKayo-I");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic XXXXX");
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    postDataParams.put("tx_name", mName);
                    postDataParams.put("tx_nickname", mNick);
                    postDataParams.put("dt_nascimento", mData);
                    postDataParams.put("tp_sexo", mSexo);
                    postDataParams.put("nu_cellphone", mNumber);
                    postDataParams.put("password", mPassword);
                    postDataParams.put("tx_email", mEmail);
                    Log.e("resource", postDataParams.toString());


                    JSONObject resource = new JSONObject();
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                    array.put(postDataParams);
                    resource.put("resource", array);

                    System.out.println(resource.toString());



                    conn.connect();

                    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                    //writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
                    writer.write(resource.toString());

                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    os.close();

                    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();





                    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PostCadastro.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);


                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                        String line = "";



                        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                            sb.append(line);
                            break;
                        }

                        in.close();
                        return sb.toString();

                    } else {
                        return new String("false : " + responseCode);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    private boolean hasContent(EditText et) {

        boolean bHasContent = false;

        if (et.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
            // Got content
            bHasContent = true;
        }
        return bHasContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu acredito que essa validação de usuário repetido seja feita no back-end, no Java vc não vai conseguir controlar isso sem fazer um request na API antes

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa fazer essa validação no back-end:

Seria necessário criar um mecanismo de pesquisa a ser executado quando o usuário clicasse no botão **cadastrar**, então, antes de você realizar o insert na base de dados, você faria um select para validar se já existe esse nome na tabela.

Caso existir então você vai precisar retornar uma mensagem ao usuário na tela de cadastro. Caso não existir você cadastra ele com sucesso.

Esse mecanismo só pode ser implementado no back-end.